# Get Token without pop-up using ADAL.js in Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-365, adal.js

I am trying to get the token from JS using ADAL.js for authentication.

In the below code, I am trying to get the cached user and token. If the user and token is not cached, I open a pop-up to a dummy page in CRM and then cache the user and the token.

```
var getUser = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // If the user is cached, resolve the promise immediately.
        var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
        if (user) {
            var cachedToken = authContext.getCachedToken(clientId);
            resolve(cachedToken);
            return;
        }

        // The user was not cached. Open a popup window which
        // performs the OAuth login process, then signals
        // the result.
        authContext.config.displayCall = function (url) {
            authContext.config.displayCall = null;
            var popup = window.open(url, 'auth-popup', 'toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=10000, top=10000, width=10, height=10, visible=none');

            var intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
                try {
                    if (popup.location.pathname.indexOf('/' + dummyAuthPage) >= 0) {

                        authContext.handleWindowCallback(popup.location.hash);
                        popup.close();
                        token = authContext.getCachedToken(clientId);
                        if (token) {
                            window.clearInterval(intervalId);
                            resolve(token);
                        }
                        else {
                            reject(authContext.getLoginError());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (whatever) {
                    if (popup.closed) {
                        reject();
                    }
                }
            }, 100);
        };
```

Do we have a better way to do the same especially without getting the pop-up?

I am currently trying to do the [Silent Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-silent-aad). But here it is mentioned "In the tab's content page, call microsoftTeams.getContext() to get a login hint for the current user". This command is not returning anything in CRM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try silent authentication described in the following docs.microsoft Link [Silent authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-silent-aad)

Comment: In this article, they mentioned "In the tab's content page, call microsoftTeams.getContext() to get a login hint for the current user", but this command will not work in CRM, right?